# Change view background color into a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to change background color on a view component, but not success

```
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    try {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_accounts, null); // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
        }
        final Account listItem = (Account) mList.get(position); // --CloneChangeRequired
        if (listItem != null) {

            int color = listItem.getColor();

            View vColor = (View) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.lv_account_view_color);

            vColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return view;
}
```

I can set some text in textview, but set color not working.

Can anybody helps me how to set the color? Thanks

The example color used is: -16711717

**edit**

Listview Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/lv_account_view_color"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#167117" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lv_account_tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

background cannot be setted in xml, it's a dynamic color

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the background color of the component in the listview_accounts.xml file of your project. For example

```
<component>
android:background="@color/color_name"
</component>
```

You have to make a color.xml file in your values folder(maybe already present) and add the color value ex:-16711717.
try this and let me know

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#167117" />
```

Comment: I can't, i choose that color in a ColorPicker, it work's when I set out of a listview, but into a listview, i't doesn't works...

Comment: Have you tried defining this color code with # like as #16711717?     <color name="mycolor">#16711717</color> and use it in your layout xml file listview_accounts as i have defined in my answer

Comment: Yes, I already tried it out a listview, and worked! But into a listview it does't work! Why can't I set backgorund color into a listview item?

Comment: can you post code of your listview_accounts.xml in which you have tried setting background so that i can take a look at it.

Comment: <View
        android:id="@+id/lv_account_view_color"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green" />

this view, there's others views like this out listview and works, but into a listview, isn't working (this code is a part of a listview item)

Comment: I have tried this code,it works for me but the color code you are trying i.e. 16711717 is not returning the exact color while the hexadecimal code for green is working... also the code 167117 works for me,try this and let me know. I have edited my answer

Comment: post the whole layout code i will try that, the code snippet I have edited is working for me, still i will check yours, kindly post the layout code

Answer (score 0):

Try this: vColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#yourcolorcode"));

Answer (score 0):

you can find solution on [This link](http://balvinder788.blogspot.in/2014/05/create-multiple-dynamic-views-to-make.html)

Just you have to change one thing. In delete.onclick method replace   list.removeView(customView); with Customview.setbackground(Color.red); etc. This may help you. Best of luck.